# ajax jquery - duplicates content after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Im making a blog list page, with *Load More...* and I have a problem. After click/load my whole content duplicates, but only the first page, doesnt duplicates, only the next pages. 
If Im open a PHP file, where's my content generated, it shows only the current page what I need to load, for example only second page

There's the whole code

```
    <?php 
    $paginationClass = 'otw_portfolio_manager-load-more-newspapper';
    $paginationLoadMore = 'otw_portfolio_manager-load-more-newspapper';

    $uniqueHash = wp_create_nonce("otw_pm_get_posts_nonce"); 
    $listID = $this->listOptions['id'];
    $maxPages = $otw_pm_posts->max_num_pages;

    $paginationPageNo = (int) $_GET['page'];
    //echo $paginationPageNo;
    ($paginationPageNo == 0) ? $page = 2 : $page = $paginationPageNo + 1;
    $ajaxURL = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id='. $listID .'&nonce='. $uniqueHash .'&page='. $page );
?>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
                var ID = $(this).attr('id');
                $('.show_more').hide();
                $('.loding').show();
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'<?php echo $ajaxURL;?>',
                    data:'id='+ID,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#show_more_main-'+ID).remove();
                        $(".row.works").append(html);
                    }
                }); 
            });
        });
    </script>


<!-- Load More Pagination -->
<div class="js-pagination_container">
    <div class="<?php echo $paginationClass;?> hide">
        <a href="<?php echo $ajaxURL;?>" class="js-pagination-no"><?php echo $page;?></a>
    </div>
    <div id="show_more_main-<?php echo $page;?>" class="<?php echo $paginationLoadMore;?> js-otw_portfolio_manager-load-more">
        <a href="<?php echo $ajaxURL;?>" data-empty="<?php _e('No more items to load.', OTW_PML_TRANSLATION);?>" data-isotope="true" class="show_more"><?php _e('Load More', OTW_PML_TRANSLATION);?></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php?>
<!-- End Load More Pagination -->
</div>
```

Console report after 3 clicks on last "Load More"

```
13:36:29.502 jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id=1&nonce=7452b3a7e4&page=2".
13:36:31.842 jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id=1&nonce=7452b3a7e4&page=2".
13:36:31.905 jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id=1&nonce=7452b3a7e4&page=3".
13:36:31.936 jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id=1&nonce=7452b3a7e4&page=3".
13:36:36.333 jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id=1&nonce=7452b3a7e4&page=4".
13:36:36.380 jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id=1&nonce=7452b3a7e4&page=2".
13:36:36.585 jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id=1&nonce=7452b3a7e4&page=3".
13:36:36.929 jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id=1&nonce=7452b3a7e4&page=4".
13:36:36.982 jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id=1&nonce=7452b3a7e4&page=3".
```

I make this function in wordpress

Comment: show your php code.

Comment: Probably because your php api returns same date over and over ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay which one? who generate a content?

Comment: @AdityaParab I forgot to write, I make it for wordpress

Comment: @DanielsJirgensons, yes.

Comment: I see.. From the information given by you, it seems it would be much easier if you create another div with class `row.content-1` which is placed right below `row.content` . And in success function you do `$(".row.content").html(html);` instead of append

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I make it in Wordpress, the admin-ajax.php is long code

Comment: check the id , may be you sending same id again, so it loads samedata.
its not clear unless you show us php code or console output. go to console -> network->XHR, check each ajax request when clicking show more

Comment: check what id it sendsw

Comment: and please add wordpress tag,

Comment: either you are sending the same ID every time, and/or your PHP is not taking the ID into account properly when deciding what data to return. You haven't shown either of those details so it's hard to say what the problem is. How many "show_more" buttons have you got? If you've only got one then it will always send the same ID to the server.

Comment: @ADyson im updated my post

Comment: @AhmedSunny Im put the console report in my post

Comment: Should you be using a GET for those ajax-admin requests, given it passes all the variables on the querystring? And how are you reading and using the value of "ID" in the ajax-admin.php script?

Comment: @ADyson actually, in html what `ajax-admin` generate, theres not ID

Comment: also I note "show_more" is an `<a href` tag, so it will normally make a fresh page request instead of ajax. You need to write `$(document).on('click','.show_more',function(event){ event.preventDefault();` to stop this

Comment: "in html what ajax-admin generate". I didn't ask that, I asked how admin-ajax _reads_ the value of ID that you try to submit in the ajax call? Nothing to do with what it outputs as HTML. Presumably you write `$id = $_POST["id"]` or something?

Answer (score 0):

Now I update and move my jquery away from php and now I see how much times it duplicates, and how it works

This is my template

```
<div class="row works">
    <?php  foreach( $otw_pm_posts->posts as $post ){

        echo $this->buildInterfacePortfolioItems( $post ); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getSocial( $post ); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getDelimiter( $post ); ?>
    <?php }?>

    <?php 
    $paginationClass = 'otw_portfolio_manager-load-more-newspapper';
    $paginationLoadMore = 'otw_portfolio_manager-load-more-newspapper';

    $uniqueHash = wp_create_nonce("otw_pm_get_posts_nonce"); 
    $listID = $this->listOptions['id'];
    $maxPages = $otw_pm_posts->max_num_pages;

    $paginationPageNo = (int) $_GET['page'];
    //echo $paginationPageNo;
    ($paginationPageNo == 0) ? $page = 2 : $page = $paginationPageNo + 1;
    $ajaxURL = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=get_pm_posts&post_id='. $listID .'&nonce='. $uniqueHash .'&page='. $page );
?>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            loadMore();
        });
    </script>


<!-- Load More Pagination -->
<div class="js-pagination_container">
    <div class="<?php echo $paginationClass;?> hide">
        <a href="<?php echo $ajaxURL;?>" class="js-pagination-no"><?php echo $page;?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="<?php echo $paginationLoadMore;?> js-otw_portfolio_manager-load-more">
        <a href="<?php echo $ajaxURL;?>" data-empty="<?php _e('No more items to load.', OTW_PML_TRANSLATION);?>" data-isotope="true" class="show_more"><?php _e('Load More', OTW_PML_TRANSLATION);?></a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php?>
<!-- End Load More Pagination -->
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery now

```
function loadMore(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more', 'a' ,function(e){
        var post = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.show_more').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:post,
            success:function(html){
                $(html).insertAfter(".row.works");
            }
        }); 
        e.stopPropagation();

    });
}
```

And how its duplicates
1. click - shows second page
2. click - 3 times duplicate third page
3. click - n times duplicate fourth page and content with second and third page content

Comment: this doesn't appear to be answer? Did you mean to edit your question with this information?

Comment: I'm confused by this: `$(document).on('click','.show_more', 'a' ,function(e){` According to http://api.jquery.com/on/, the third argument to "on" is "Data to be passed to the handler in event.data when an event is triggered.". Why do you want to pass the character "a" to the event data? You don't seem to use it, anyhow.

Comment: Anyway, what does "admin-ajax.php" do? You haven't shown it, unless that's the code you've called the "template", above? We don't know what page numbers your links are sending it, or what logic it uses to try and return the right posts.

Comment: admin-ajax.php make the posts, generate a HTML for next page

Comment: Ok, but unfortunately a verbal description doesn't help me to help you. I need to see a) what page numbers you send it in each of the examples above, and b) what it does with those page numbers in order to try and generate the right content to return (i.e. I need to see the relevant part(s) of the code from that script). Clearly there's some sort of logical error in there.